# How to open Childform without changing value?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a MainForm, I create a panel to open childform with a button in MainForm. But when i changed somethings in Childform and i click button to open childform again from MainForm, Which change i did in childform not exists anymore.
That's my problem. Please help me, Tks.

My code in mainform:

```
private void btnRoom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormRoom fr = new FormRoom();
    fr.TopLevel = false; 
    panelDesktopPanel.Controls.Add(fr); 
    fr.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; 
    fr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; fr.BringToFront(); fr.Show(); 
    ActivateButton(sender); 
    lblTitle.Text = fr.Text;
}
```

Comment: private void btnRoom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Forms.FormRoom fr = new Forms.FormRoom();
            fr.TopLevel = false;
            panelDesktopPanel.Controls.Add(fr);
            fr.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            fr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            fr.BringToFront();
            fr.Show();
            ActivateButton(sender);
            lblTitle.Text = fr.Text;
        }

Comment: You can simply cut-and-paste your code directly from Visual Studio! You just have to make sure the code block in the markdown view is entirely indented by four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straightforward to achieve your objective but there is one "trick" you have to know. So, first, make `fr` a *member* of the main form class and add it to the `Controls` collection of `panelDesktopPanel` from the start. Its visibility is set to `false` so it's not going to show until you want it to.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        checkBoxRoom.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
        checkBoxRoom.CheckedChanged += onCheckedChangedRoom;
        Disposed += (sender, e) =>fr.Dispose();
        panelDesktopPanel.Controls.Add(fr);
    }

    FormRoom fr = new FormRoom
    {
        Visible = false,
        TopLevel = false,
        FormBorderStyle= FormBorderStyle.None,
        Dock= DockStyle.Fill,
        BackColor= Color.Azure,
    };
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The part I mentioned that requires special handling is when a `Form` visibility is going to be cycled multiple times. Because you are setting the `FormBorderStyle` to `None` this issue will be minimal in your project. But other times when the [**X**] box is visible to `Close` the form you have to be very careful that the OS doesn't dispose the underlying window handle.

In an abundance of caution, lets make sure that the `Handle` of `FormRoom` can't be destroyed in that manner by overriding the `FormClosing` event.

```
class FormRoom : Form
{
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        // Disallow close by [X] hide instead.
        FormClosing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.Cancel = e.CloseReason.Equals(CloseReason.UserClosing);
            Hide();
        };
    }
}
```

---

**Test**

For testing purposes, I replaced your [**Room**] button with a checkbox that *looks* like a button so we can cycle its visibility and it appears that all is well!

[image: screenshot]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    .
    .
    .
    private void onCheckedChangedRoom(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fr.Visible = checkBoxRoom.Checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks Sir. Im done!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Did this answer help you, or did you figure it out some other way?